# Accessing Cassandra Filtering allowed need to be added

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

I have Cassandra Table as below

```
create table user(
id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
firstname varchar,
secondname varchar,
emailid varchar,
);
```

From Java - Spring Boot Im trying to access data

```
Optional<User> findByEmailid(String emailId);
```

I get error stating

It asks me to use "FILTERING ALLOWED" part of query. Is there anyway to enable this globally or I should change query/db structure?

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you that `emailid` is not a valid column that can be filtered on in your WHERE clause.  Enabling `ALLOW FILTERING` or creating a secondary index on that column is one way to do this.  But both of those are pretty terrible solutions (because of how Cassandra is works under-the-hood).

With Cassandra you need to take a query-based modeling approach.  This means that sometimes (often) queries and tables share a 1:1 ratio.  If you really need to query users by email address, then you will need to create a table to serve that query.

```
CREATE TABLE user_by_email(
  id UUID,
  firstname varchar,
  secondname varchar,
  emailid varchar PRIMARY KEY,
);
```

Then something like this will work:

```
Optional<UserByEmail> findByEmailid(String emailId);
```

And if you don't ever plan on querying the `user` table by `id`, then there really isn't a reason to use that column as your sole primary key.

Comment: Does it mean that I should always query with PRIMARY KEY? I can not filter with other columns?

Comment: @syv correct.  Always need to build your primary keys with whichever columns you intend on querying by.

Comment: Thank you. I had gone through the design in detail there are 3 options suggested 1. Need to relook at the Data model 2. Allow Filter 3. Adding Index.